# PostgreSQL query from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

Question about querying PostgreSQL.
It's simple to do by stored procedure or inside any programming language, but my question is it possible to do by one select statement. This is an example of two tables.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Third table Output on image

Comment: If it is simply by stored procedure or inside any programming code, give an example of that and we can help turn it into plain SELECT statements - though usually the problem is going in the other direction, from SELECT statements to application language code.

Comment: May I e-mail cod to you ?  The website don't give me put code  in correct format.

Comment: @Green_Crocodile Please post your code in your question so that your question can be helpful for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for formatting help. Code must be indented by 4 spaces to display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally do the "group headers" in some kind of *reporting tool*. However, it can all be done in pure SQL, if you wish.

You start with the data in a "standard JOIN":

```
-- The basic query
SELECT
    table_1.table_1_id, phone, name, some_data, 
    row_number() over(partition by table_1.table_1_id order by some_data)
FROM
    table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id ;
```

That will produce the following table:

```
table_1_id | phone | name | some_data | row_number
---------: | :---- | :--- | :-------- | ---------:
         1 | 502   | aa   | a         |          1
         1 | 502   | aa   | b         |          2
         1 | 502   | aa   | j         |          3
         1 | 502   | aa   | n         |          4

         2 | 268   | bb   | a         |          1
         2 | 268   | bb   | s         |          2
         2 | 268   | bb   | y         |          3

         5 | 984   | ee   | a         |          1
         5 | 984   | ee   | n         |          2
         5 | 984   | ee   | w         |          3
```

If you want to *add* some header rows and also *not show* the values of `phone, name, we need to *add* these data to the query. This is done by making a second specific`SELECT`for the headers, and`UNION ALL` with the first one.

That is, we will use:

```
-- This query produces the 'headers'
SELECT DISTINCT
    table_1.table_1_id, 
    phone, 
    name, 
    '' AS some_data, 
    true as is_header   -- this marks this row as a 'header'
FROM
    table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id

UNION ALL

-- This query produces the actual data
SELECT
    table_1.table_1_id, 
    phone,
    name, 
    some_data, 
    false as is_header
FROM
    table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id ;
```

Now, we make this a *sub*query, and make some extra logic to decide which data needs to be shown, and which one needs to be hidden (actually, shown as ''):

```
-- A few tricks to do the formatting
SELECT
    -- Here we decide which information to show, which not
    case when is_header then cast(table_1_id as text) else '' end AS table_1_id,
    case when is_header then phone                    else '' end AS phone,
    case when is_header then name                     else '' end as name,
    case when is_header then ''                       else some_data end as some_data
FROM
    (-- This query produces the 'headers'
    SELECT DISTINCT
        table_1.table_1_id, 
        phone, 
        name, 
        '' AS some_data, 
        true as is_header   -- this marks this row as a 'header
    FROM
        table_1
        JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id
    UNION ALL
    -- This query produces the actual data
    SELECT
        table_1.table_1_id, 
        phone,
        name, 
        some_data, 
        false as is_header
    FROM
        table_1
        JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id
    ) AS q
ORDER BY
    q.table_1_id, is_header DESC /* Header goes first */, some_data ;
```

This produces:

```
table_1_id | phone | name | some_data
:--------- | :---- | :--- | :--------
1          | 502   | aa   |          
           |       |      | a        
           |       |      | b        
           |       |      | j        
           |       |      | n        
2          | 268   | bb   |          
           |       |      | a        
           |       |      | s        
           |       |      | y        
5          | 984   | ee   |          
           |       |      | a        
           |       |      | n        
           |       |      | w
```

You can see the whole setup and the simulated data at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a9313f92b438893f39f8a41e2c5498f6)*

---

Note that the *order* that you specified is not preserved. You should have some *logic* on how things should get ordered. SQL doesn't have a concept of "insert order" or "natural order"; you always have to choose which one you want (otherwise, the database will choose the one it is most convenient *for it*, and that *may* change from one execution to the next).

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=159bee342778bfc88a6e138e29f45999 - see the last query.

Comment: @Abelisto: I think we agree: you're showing nulls where I am showing the empty string. It's just about *presentation*.

Comment: It is not about result representation but about query (it seems you missed it).

Comment: Thank you very much  joanolo ,  excellent and full explanation.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Abelisto: you're using grouping sets to make the query much shorter, and probably close to optimal in terms of execution plan! Actually much better than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is the nice feature like [`grouping sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).

Using it you could to get in single query/result set several sets for different grouping conditions. Thanks for example data to [joanolo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a9313f92b438893f39f8a41e2c5498f6)

Lets start at the most simple query:

```
SELECT
  table_1.table_1_id, phone, name, some_data
FROM
  table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id;
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ table_1_id │ phone │ name │ some_data │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ a         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ b         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ n         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ j         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ w         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ a         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ n         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ s         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ a         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ y         │
└────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

Here wee need to add the groups by first three columns:

```
SELECT
  table_1.table_1_id, phone, name--, some_data
FROM
  table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((table_1.table_1_id, phone, name));
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ table_1_id │ phone │ name │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │
└────────────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Note double parenthesizes. Actually it is equal to the simple `GROUP BY table_1.table_1_id, phone, name` (that's because I commented out `some_data` column, it is not in the group). But we wants to add to our query more data:

```
SELECT
  table_1.table_1_id, phone, name, some_data
FROM
  table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id
GROUP By GROUPING SETS ((table_1.table_1_id, phone, name),(table_1.table_1_id, phone, name, some_data));
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ table_1_id │ phone │ name │ some_data │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ a         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ b         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ j         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ n         │
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ ░░░░      │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ a         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ s         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ y         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ ░░░░      │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ a         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ n         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ w         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ ░░░░      │
└────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

It is almost what we wants. We need just to order the data in proper way and clean some columns:

```
SELECT
    case when some_data is null then table_1.table_1_id end as table_1_id,
    case when some_data is null then phone end as phone,
    case when some_data is null then name end as name,
    some_data
FROM
    table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id
group by grouping sets((table_1.table_1_id, phone, name), (table_1.table_1_id, phone, name, some_data))
order by table_1.table_1_id, some_data nulls first;
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ table_1_id │ phone │ name │ some_data │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│          1 │ 502   │ aa   │ ░░░░      │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ a         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ b         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ j         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ n         │
│          2 │ 268   │ bb   │ ░░░░      │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ a         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ s         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ y         │
│          5 │ 984   │ ee   │ ░░░░      │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ a         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ n         │
│       ░░░░ │ ░░░░  │ ░░░░ │ w         │
└────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

Bingo! Hope it is what you asking for.